# Inserting element inside an XML document using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Have a XML string like below:

```
<stages>
<params/>
<test description=""/>
</stages>
```

I want to add the following XML string after `<test desc.../>` tag OR before the end of stages i.e. `</stages>`

```
<stage id="myId" level="1">
```

and all subsequent stages.

Post-addition it should like

```
<stages>
    <params/>
    <test description=""/>
    <stage id="myId" level="1"/>
    <stage id=.../>
    ...
</stages>
```

I am trying to do something like this:

```
var stageNode = document.createTextNode(
                        "<stage id=\"myId\" level=\"1\">")              
                );
var root = document.getElementsByTagName("test").parentNode;
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("test")); //<-- giving [] in console log and root is undefined; though the element is there
var stages = root.getElementsByTagName("stage");
root.insertBefore(stageNode,stages.nextSibling);
```

How can I do this in JavaScript or JQuery?

Using DocumentBuilder or DocumentBuilderFactory is giving me "Unexpected identifier" error. Is there an easier way to do the above using document builder in Javascript (as in Java)?

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery it might look like so:

```js
function addStage(xmlDocument, stageElement){
  var parent = $(xmlDocument).find("test").parent(); //picks <test>'s parent
  parent.append(stageElement); //appends stageElement to parent
}

var xmlString = '<stages><params/><test description=""/></stages>'; //your XML string
var xmlDocument = $.parseXML(xmlString); //parses your XML string and returns XML document

$("#addStage").click(function(){
  var id = $("#stageId").val();
  var stageElement = $("<stage id=\"" + id + "\"></stage>"); //creates new element
  addStage(xmlDocument, stageElement);
  console.log(xmlDocument);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
Stage ID: <input type="text" id="stageId" /> <input type="button" id="addStage" value="Add stage" />
```

Open browser's console to see the results.

Answer (score 0):

Using Plain Old JavaScript:

```
var text = "<stages><params/><test description=\"\"/></stages>";

var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");

var newNode = xmlDoc.createElement("stage");
newNode.setAttribute("id", "myId");
newNode.setAttribute("level", "1");
xmlDoc.documentElement.appendChild(newNode);

newNode = xmlDoc.createElement("stage");
newNode.setAttribute("id", "myId2");
newNode.setAttribute("level", "2");
xmlDoc.documentElement.appendChild(newNode);

console.log(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlDoc.documentElement));
```

For reference on adding node at a particular position, refer [XML DOM Add Nodes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_nodes_add.asp)